# Thinking of Porting MVC3/EF/SQL Server application to Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have a web application. It uses:

1) MVC3/ASP.NET4/C#.

2) Entity Framework 4.1. Model in dedicated VS project.

3) 3rd party .NET libraries.

4) Sql Server 2008 SP2 Standard (could use web for deployment), not Express

5) Membership Services

I am looking for:

1) Scalability for commercial performance.

2) Quick Backup and restore of SQL DBs in case of emergencies.

3) Ease of deployment. FTP or GIT. Currently use FTP file difference process.

4) Support for Redgate DB sync tools that a non Azure Shared host might provide.

5) Monitoring of performance and usage.

6) Exception reporting of errors.

I would like to host it on Azure for its resilience and scalability benefits. Also I do not want to be preoccupied with maintaining infrastructure. So PAAS has it attractions, rather than IAAS.

My initial thoughts are:

1) Azure "Reserved" websites features.

2) Not sure about SQL server. Is it simplest to use the Azure SQL Server Service?

What would be the best AZURE fit for my purposes?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Yes I guess DiscountASP is similar to GoDaddy, in that it is a shared host. However it is a specialised ASP.NET host. Theoretically since I am able to use DiscountASP, then using Azure Websites and Azure SQL Database would be the match. As you say, best to play and find out. Cloud services looks really interesting. I can see from all of this a path to follow for more sophistication. To start with I would want to keep it simple. However I might choose to take advantage of Cloud Services later. I get the feeling one needs to take account of Cloud services much more in the development, since one deploys cloud services from VS.

EDIT2:

An interesting point is made here in that Cloud Services is deployed from VS. So does this mean the that use of Cloud Services has to be more baked into the Software design, whereas Azure Websites can be just ported to. Okay I realise this means using managed code with a maximum of medium trust etc. But I have the application now, and I would not want to redevelop chunks of it to fit the cloud services models, although later on the code will be upgraded and this is when I quess the Cloud Service integration could occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use 3rd party .NET libs, I believe that you have to choose Windows Azure Virtual Machines, but you'll be responsible for maintaining this environment.

Without that, you could go with Windows Azure Cloud Services (for MVC) and Windows Azure SQL Database (Sql Azure).

The best you can do is deploy your app to Azure and test it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you tell me a little more about the restrictions on the 3rd party .NET DLLs. Currently I use DiscountASP for hosting the application and it works fine. So this is my benchmark. It is a shared environment so imposes expected "Shared" restrictions. I would expect "Azure Websites" to be similar, but not more restrictive. If I cannot get Azure to work in time then I will most likely stay with DiscountASP. It does work, but I would like more scalability.

Comment: If VMs are the way to go, then fine, but I would rather not go there unless there is no option, since my focus is software rather than infrastructure. Thanks again

Comment: @SamJolly I don't know DiscountASP. It's a kind of Godaddy? If the answer is yes, it's similar to Windows Azure Web Sites. For simple websites it's great, but as you need more flexible (read install 3rd party tools / libs) you should go with Windows Azure Cloud Services or Windows Azure Virtual Machines. Here's a link that shows the differences among the execution models: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/choose-web-app-service/

Comment: Thanks for this. See EDIT . An interesting point is made here in that Cloud Services is deployed from VS. So does this mean the that use of Cloud Services has to be more baked into the Software design, whereas Azure Websites can be just ported to. Okay I realise this means using managed code with a maximum of medium trust etc. But I have the application now, and I would not want to redevelop chunks of it to fit the cloud services models, although later one the code will be upgraded and this is when I quess the Cloud Service integration could occur.

Comment: @SamJolly you can publish to a Windows Azure Web Sites through VS too.